# Excel - How to find location (i.e. what columns) of specific PivotFields in a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, pivot-table

I am building a routine that automates creating a PivotTable.  All is working well...I add my rows, columns, filters and values.  As a last step, I want to format the values.  I cannot find any property that shows me what "value entry/pivotfield" ends up in which column.  Lets assume that I have 2 Value PivotFields...

```
Pivot1 := fmyPivotTable.AddDataField( 'Revenue', 'Revenue', xlSum );
Pivot2 := fmyPivotTable.AddDataField( 'Locations', 'Locations', xlCount );
```

I am looking for something that will  tell me that Pivot1 data is in columns C, E and G while Pivot2 data is in D,F and H.  The closest I could find is labelrange and position, but neither of these is really what I need.  I am writing this in Delphi, but if someone knows how to do this in VBA, I can convert.

ADDITIONAL INFO.
The code I am using looks similar to this.  (I had to cut out some irrelevant stuff).  What I am looking for is a way to determine what columns will hold the data from v1 and v2.

```
  var
    // Filter Fields
      f1, f2: OleVariant;
      // Row Fields
      r1, r2 : OleVariant;
      // Column Fields
      c1: OleVariant;
      // Value Fields
      v1, v2: OleVariant;
      PivotStartAddr: String;
      OrigDataRange: ExcelRange;      
      myPivotCache: PivotCache;
      myPivotTable: PivotTable; 
      RawSheet, PivotSheet1 : _Worksheet;


    begin

      RawSheet := oExcel.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet;
      OrigDataRange := RawSheet.Range['A1', 'BA35285'];

      // Create a Pivot Cache
      myPivotCache := oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,OrigDataRange,xlPivotTableVersion15);

      // Create a New Sheet 
      oExcel.Worksheets.Add(EmptyParam, RawSheet, 1, xlWorksheet, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);
      PivotSheet1 := oExcel.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet;
      PivotSheet1.Name := 'Pivot Sheet';

     // Create a Pivot table within the PivotCache
       PivotStartAddr :=  'R4C1';
       myPivotTable := myPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(PivotStartAddr, 'PivotTable56', EmptyParam,xlPivotTableVersion15);

       // Add Filter Fields
       f1 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('OVI_MAJOR');
       f1.Caption := 'Industry';
       f1.Orientation := xlPageField;
       f1.Position :=1 ;

       f2 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('APPS_ORG_TYPE');
       f2.Caption := 'Apps';
       f2.Orientation := xlPageField;
       f2.Position :=2 ;

       // Add Rows  
       r1 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('PARENT_ACCOUNT_NAME');
       r1.Caption := 'l Name';
       r1.Orientation := xlRowField;
       r1.Position := 1;

       r2 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('ACCOUNT');
       r2.Caption := 'Account';
       r2.Orientation := xlRowField;
       r2.Position := 2;

       // Add Columns
       c1 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('CLOUD_MARKETING_SEGMENT');
       c1.Caption := 'Mkt Segment';
       c1.Orientation := xlColumnField;
       c1.Position := 1;


       v1 := myPivotTable.AddDataField('SIC', 'SIC', xlCount);
       v2 := myPivotTable.AddDataField('REVENUE', 'Revenue', xlSum);
       end;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm suffering from brain-fade, but the more I try to follow what your problem is, the harder I find it.  When you add summary columns to a pivot table, afaik they necessarily appear immediately to the right of the unsummarised ones and if I try to shift them to other columns, Excel will not let me.  So, istm you know where the pivot table is being inserted, and what the unsummarised columns and the summary columns are, so you should know and where they will be, i.e. in the columns immediately to the right of the unsummarised ones, no?

Comment: @@MartynA, in the simplest example, you are correct. In the example above the number of SIC columns and Revenue columns, which are my summaries, depend on the number of values of the column field, Cloud_Marketing_Segment.  My data has 3 values for Cloud_Marketing_Segment, plus blanks, plus Totals, so that means that I will have alternating columns of 5 sets of SIC then Revenue.  This gets much more complicated when I have multiple levels of columns.  I can possibly figure it out based on the column name, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Thanks.  My own attempts to wring the info about a PT have so far failed miserably.  Good luck!

Comment: @@MartynA - This is actually for an Excel library for Delphi.  I do a lot of Excel work. Let me know if you would like a copy.

Comment: Thanks, that's very generous of you.  If I manage to catch up with other stuff sometime soon, I'll take you up on that.